# How does animi describe mind?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, theology

St Augustine remarked:

> sedis animi est in memoria

Hannah Arendt translates this as:

> The seat of the mind is memory

The Descartian division between mind and body is so pervasive, that one concieves mind as being disembodied; and in one genealogy derives from Avicennas disembodied 'floating man'.

But in the above it is *animi* that translates mind; not knowing Latin, or Augustinian thought I'd speculate that *animi* means that which animates; which ties it to the body (thinking of Aristotles notion of *hylomorphism*); is this uninformed guess correct?

Comment: @kingsbury: the links broken.

Comment: Bad formatting on earlier comment: Here's the [Perseus project dictionary entry for animus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph%3Fl%3Danimus%26la%3Dla%26can%3Danimus0%26prior%3Dmortalium%26d%3DPerseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0124%3Achapter%3D1%26i%3D1%23lexicon&r=&t=0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

anima (genitive is animi) means "soul" and it is the root of "animate". The soul in this sense is just generally identified with whatever it is that makes the organism alive. The anima is sometimes thought of as the location of intellectual cognition.

The word "spiritus" from which we get the english word "Spirit" is a synonym. Literally it just means 'breath' (cf. 'respiration'). The connection between breath and life is common in the ancient near east as well. See Genesis 2.7.

Comment: So presumably it translates the Greek *pneuma*?